# Calculating Sum of specific arraylist elements in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, sum, integer

I am trying to create a airline points program that accepts user input for their first and last name as well as flyers points for 4 weeks, as shown in the snapshot below. The "Total Points" button should add up the flyers points from week one to four, and accesses their points in the array list based off their last name.

[image: Airline Points GUI]

The program should also check to see if their points are over 5000, and give them a bonus 1000 points if so.

While I have the rest of the program working fine, **I am having trouble with my loop accessing and adding up the sum of the flyers points.**
When I click the Total Points button, the amount of points is showing up  as "0"
What am I doing wrong? I am somewhat new to programming so finding logic errors is not yet my strong suit.

```java
public class AirlinePointsApp

   ArrayList <plane> rewards = new ArrayList <plane>();

private void pointsButtonActionPerformed

        //Define Variables
        
        int points = 0;
        int difference = 5000-points;
        String lastIn;
        
        lastIn = lastInput.getText();
        for (int x = 0; x <= (rewards.size()-1); x++){
            while (x <= rewards.size()-1 + 4){
                points = points + x;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (points > 5000){
            rewardOutput.setText("Congrats, flyer! You are eligible for an additional 1000 points bonus.\nHappy flying!");
        }
        else {
            rewardOutput.setText("'" + lastIn + "' has " + points + " flyers points. They need an additional " + difference + "\npoints to qualify for a bonus.");
        }
```

Comment: `while-break`? That's an `if` statement!!

Comment: Also why `x <= (rewards.size()-1)` ? It can be simply `x < rewards.size()`

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I would advise removing anything that is not necessary.

Comment: @MostNeededRabbit When I click the Total Points button, the amount of points is showing up as "0"